# Linear regression with visualization

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematics, machine-learning, matplotlib

I have created a small script that:

1. Creates a lot of random points.
2. Runs a small brute force search to find a rect that has a low error, that is a good fit for the data.
3. Runs a linear regression on the rect generated with brute force to further reduce the error.
4. Prints out information and plots the data.

Down here you can see an example graph: the random points in blue, the brute forced rect, in blue, the 'linear regressed' rect in green.

[image: The random points in blue, the brute forced rect, in blue, the 'linear regressed' rect in green.]

```
from __future__ import division
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
import numpy as np

def random_point():
    return (random.random(),random.random())

def list_of_random_points(n):
    return [random_point() for _ in range(n)]

def error_of_point(point,function):
    x,y = point[0],point[1]
    return abs(y - function(x))

def error_of_list_of_points(points,function):
    return sum((error_of_point(point,function) for point in points))


def get_starting_rect(points):
    min_error = 10**10
    for m1 in range(-10,10):
        for q1 in range(-10,10):
            m,q = m1/10,q1/10
            function = lambda x: m*x + q
            if error_of_list_of_points(points,function) < min_error:
                min_error = error_of_list_of_points(points,function)
                best_mq = m,q
    return best_mq

def get_approximate_m(m,q,points,sensibility):
    if error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: (m+sensibility)*x+q) < error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q):
        m += sensibility
    elif error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: (m-sensibility)*x+q) < error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q):
        m -= sensibility
    return m

def get_approximate_q(m,q,points,sensibility):
    if error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: (m)*x+q+sensibility) < error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q):
        q += sensibility
    elif error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: (m)*x+q-sensibility) < error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q):
        q -= sensibility
    return q

def approximate_better_m_and_q(m,q,points,sensibility):
    for _ in range(100):
        m = get_approximate_m(m,q,points,sensibility)
        q = get_approximate_q(m,q,points,sensibility)
    sensibility /= 10
    for _ in range(100):
        m = get_approximate_m(m,q,points,sensibility)
        q = get_approximate_q(m,q,points,sensibility)
    return m,q

def plot_rect(m,q):
    x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
    y = [i*m + q for  i in x]
    p.plot(x,y)

def plot_rect_and_points(rect,points):
    p.scatter(*zip(*points))
    m,q = rect
    plot_rect(m,q)

def main():
    NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 1000
    points = list_of_random_points(NUMBER_OF_POINTS)


    m,q = get_starting_rect(points)
    plot_rect(m,q)

    print("""The rect generated with brute force of equation y = {}x + {} 
has an error of {}""".format(m,q,error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q)))

    better_rect = approximate_better_m_and_q(m,q,points,0.1)
    m,q = better_rect
    print("""The rect generated with linear regression of equation y = {}x + {} 
starting from the rect generated with
brute force has an error of {}""".format(
    m,q,error_of_list_of_points(points,lambda x: m*x + q)))

    plot_rect_and_points((m,q),points)
    p.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What does "rect" mean here?

Comment: @Veedrac rect means line.

Comment: @JanneKarila the review is about the code with rect changing it in line would invalidate the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason there's a trend among scientific Python users to import things with really short names, like

```
import numpy as np
```

This is somewhat bearable when it's `np` and you use it many times, but you use `np` **once**. Further, you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
```

and only use this *three times*. It's not worth it; typing `pyplot` three times isn't going to make your code unduly long.

You should add more spacing in accordance to PEP 8, and cap line lengths to something less than what you currently have (100 characters should be enough).

`random_point` can just be

```
def random_point():
    return random.random(), random.random()
```

Namely, no brackets needed. You only use it once in

```
def list_of_random_points(n):
    return [random_point() for _ in range(n)]
```

so just write

```
def list_of_random_points(n):
    return [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(n)]
```

instead. I'd also rename this to `random_points`. In fact, you only use *this* once, so I'd remove the function here too.

You only use `error_of_point` in `error_of_list_of_points`, so inline it, giving:

```
def error_of_list_of_points(points, func):
    return sum(abs(y - func(x)) for x, y in points)
```

You don't actually need a list, so call this `error_in_points` or similar.

In `get_starting_rect`, change

```
function = lambda x: m*x + q
```

to

```
def line(x): return m*x + q
```

I would also put it on two lines for readability. Since you use this so much, it makes sense to do

```
def line(m, q):
    def y(x):
        return m*x + q
    return y
```

So you can just do

```
error_in_points(points, line(m, q))
```

This also simplified the loop:

```
for m in range(-10, 10):
    for q in range(-10, 10):
        if error_in_points(points, line(m / 10, q / 10)) < min_error:
            ...
```

You can then move to using `min`:

```
mqs = product(range(-10, 10), range(-10, 10))
mqs = ((m/10, q/10) for m, q in mqs)

return min(mqs, key=lambda mq: error_in_points(points, line(*mq)))
```

or even

```
mqs = numpy.mgrid[-1:+1:0.1, -1:+1:0.1].reshape(2, -1).T
return min(mqs, key=lambda mq: error_in_points(points, line(*mq)))
```

`get_approximate_m` now looks like

```
def get_approximate_m(m, q, points, sensibility):
    if error_in_points(points, line(m+sensibility, q)) < error_in_points(points, line(m, q)):
        m += sensibility
    elif error_in_points(points, line(m-sensibility, q)) < error_in_points(points, line(m, q)):
        m -= sensibility
    return m
```

You should cache `error_in_points(points, line(m, q))`:

```
def get_approximate_m(m, q, points, sensibility):
    current_err = error_in_points(points, line(m, q))

    if error_in_points(points, line(m+sensibility, q)) < current_err:
        m += sensibility
    elif error_in_points(points, line(m-sensibility, q)) < current_err:
        m -= sensibility
    return m
```

This would also be better named `adjust_m` or similar.

Your `approximate_better_m_and_q` does:

```
for _ in range(100):
    m = adjust_m(m, q, points,sensibility)
    q = get_approximate_q(m, q, points, sensibility)
```

Since this does not change `sensibility` as it progresses it's likely that this quickly stops doing anything productive, spending most of its time bouncing around a few points. It'll probably work better with a gradual slowing:

```
def approximate_better_m_and_q(m, q, points, sensibility):
    for _ in range(50):
        m = get_approximate_m(m, q, points, sensibility)
        q = get_approximate_q(m, q, points, sensibility)
        sensibility *= 0.95
    return m, q
```

Which does tend to improve the results for me even though it has a quater the number of iterations.

`plot_rect` can trivially use Numpy's broadcasting:

```
def plot_rect(m,q):
    x = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    y = x * m + q
    pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

`plot_rect_and_points` can use unpacking (as can `main`):

```
plot_rect(*rect)
```

I hadn't realized that `error_in_points` is only used with `line` as the funciton; maybe you should move it into `error_in_points` to make calling more convenient.

You should split your `print`s up:

```
print("The rect generated with brute force of equation y = {}x + {}".format(m, q))
print("has an error of {}".format(error_in_points(points, m, q)))
```

although the trailing space suggests maybe you didn't realize they were printing on separate lines.

All in all this gives

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy
import random

from matplotlib import pyplot

def error_in_points(points, m, q):
    return sum(abs(y - (m*x + q)) for x, y in points)

def get_starting_rect(points):
    mqs = numpy.mgrid[-1:+1:0.1, -1:+1:0.1].reshape(2, -1).T
    return min(mqs, key=lambda mq: error_in_points(points, *mq))

def adjust_m(m, q, points, sensibility):
    current_err = error_in_points(points, m, q)

    if error_in_points(points, m+sensibility, q) < current_err:
        m += sensibility
    elif error_in_points(points, m-sensibility, q) < current_err:
        m -= sensibility
    return m

def adjust_q(m, q, points, sensibility):
    current_err = error_in_points(points, m, q)

    if error_in_points(points, m, q+sensibility) < current_err:
        q += sensibility
    elif error_in_points(points, m, q-sensibility) < current_err:
        q -= sensibility
    return q

def approximate_better_m_and_q(m, q, points, sensibility):
    for _ in range(50):
        m = adjust_m(m, q, points, sensibility)
        q = adjust_q(m, q, points, sensibility)
        sensibility *= 0.95
    return m, q

def plot_rect(m,q):
    x = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    y = x * m + q
    pyplot.plot(x,y)

def plot_rect_and_points(rect,points):
    pyplot.scatter(*zip(*points))
    plot_rect(*rect)

def main():
    NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 1000
    points = [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_POINTS)]

    m, q = get_starting_rect(points)
    plot_rect(m, q)

    print("The rect generated with brute force of equation y = {}x + {}".format(m, q))
    print("has an error of {}".format(error_in_points(points, m, q)))

    better_rect = approximate_better_m_and_q(m, q, points, 0.1)
    m, q = better_rect
    print("The rect generated with linear regression of equation y = {}x + {}".format(m, q))
    print("starting from the rect generated with brute force has an error of {}".format(
        error_in_points(points, m, q)
    ))

    plot_rect_and_points((m,q),points)
    pyplot.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is a lot more you can do (particularly vectorization), but this is a good start.

Comment: Excellent review, just as personal style I would like to keep my small functions, I like them.

Comment: @Caridorc I mentioned merging these functions because they are below a logical unit of work; `error_of_list_of_points` ended up *shorter* once you removed the function indirection. I'm totally fine with something like `plot_rect`, though.